# Entry does not publish

Tags: entry

The Craft CMS I am using doesn't want to publish the blogs I am writing. Why?

Comment: Your question is way to broad. In order to help you we need much more information. Is your blog post an entry? Did you specify a valid publish date? Is your expiry date in the past? Please contact your developer first

Comment: Hi Michael, welcome to Craft Slack. I think it's fine that your question is not from a programmer's POV... a content editor has just as much right to be asking questions about Craft CMS. That said, your actual question is way to short & broad to be answerable. I'm going to close as "too broad"... feel free to edit the question if you'd like it reopened.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to speak to the developer of your site. Craft is more a system for building a CMS than a CMS itself. Consequently there are a thousand ways your site could be put together and even more reasons why something may not be working.

If you can get some more information then there are many people who, I am sure, would be happy to help. It's just not possible to answer your question with the information provided.